# HEALpy - Getting spherical harmonics from as function of pixel, l and m

Tags: healpy

I am in need to calculate an integral of spherical harmonics and their products of different orders (l,m) over a fraction of a sphere (let's say for simplicity over a half a sphere).

Healpix/Healpy package makes it very easy and fast to calculate spherical harmonics transform be replacing an integral of a function times spherical harmonics (SH) with a sum of function*SH  values in a predefined pixel (see [this link](https://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov/html/intronode6.htm)).

However, I do not see how to get explicit values of spherical harmonics from healpy directly (i.e. just a function something like Ylm(index,l,m)).

I tried so far to use a package [sphtools](https://github.com/SHTOOLS/SHTOOLS) which has spherical harmonics function, and translate it into healpix with a simple code:

```py
import numpy as np
    
import pyshtools as pysh
import healpy as hp
    
def Ylm_sphtools(theta,phi,l,m,csphase=-1):
    Ylm_sphtools= np.vectorize(pysh.expand.spharm_lm)(l,m,theta,phi,normalization='ortho',kind='complex',                                     degrees=False,csphase=csphase)
    return Ylm_sphtools

def get_Ylm_healpy(nside,l,m):
    npix=hp.nside2npix(nside)
    theta,phi=hp.pix2ang(nside,np.arange(npix))
    return Ylm_sphtools(theta,phi,l,m)
```

```
>get_Ylm_healpy(512,10,5)
```

does what it needs: gives me the values of Y(l=10,m=5) for every pixel on a healpy map with NSIDE=512, but as one may have understood this is very slow (compared with the speed of healpy.anafast function and so on).

So my question is: how can I get spherical harmonics (real and imag.) pars over a healpix map? The integration from this point is simple: sum the values of your Ylm over a mask of interest and it's done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[The answer](https://sourceforge.net/p/healpix/mailman/message/37205075/) from one of healpix's designers, Erik Hivon.

To get the spherical harmonics `Ylm` or order `l,m` in healpix format with `nside`, one does:

```
import healpy, numpy
alms  = numpy.zeros(  ((l+1)*(l+2) - (l-m)*(l-m+1))//2 , dtype=complex)
alms[-1] = amplitude
ylm = healpy.alm2map(alms, nside=nside, pol=False, sigma=0.0, lmax=l, mmax=m)
```

`amplitude = 0.5` for the real part of the function, and `amplitude = 0.5j` for the imaginary.

The result is the difference of real and imaginary part (imaginary part should be multiplied by `1j`).

Seems legit, I will test it and report the results soon here.

EDIT:
Yes, this works. It reproduces well the `map2alm` command if one uses not `healpy.map2alm`, but integrals of spherical harmonics obtained above.